# MATCH or VLOOKUP starting from the end of the range

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a table that looks like this

```
 A      B    
ID1  data 123
ID2  data 234
ID1  data 456
ID2  data 567
```

I am trying to find the best way to retrieve `data 567` for ID2.
Using MATCH (with option 0) or VLOOKUP (with option FALSE) on ID2 gives me access to the first record but I want to retrieve the last record.

I am using Excel 2010.

ps: I'd rather not use VBA or manipulate the data (sorting...).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With data in A1:B4 and D1="ID2", try entering in E1:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A4=D1),B1:B4)
```

Note: LOOKUP returns the last value if the lookup value is larger than any of the values in the lookup range. Any errors are ignored.

Comment: This is extremely cool :-) Although I am not sure I understand the 1/(A1:A4=D1) trick...

Comment: @assylias, that creates an array that has a 1 (TRUE) for those rows that match the ID and an error (#DIV/0!) for those that don't match. `Lookup` ignores the errors. The array looks like this: {#DIV/0!;1;#DIV/0!;1} and since the lookup value of 2 is greater than 1 (which is the largest value this array can have), it returns the last item.

Comment: Does any one know how to return the last value if the lookup value is smaller than any of the values in the lookup range?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered, but if any one is interested, here is the formula for a **multiple criteria** backwards lookup. `=LOOKUP(2,1/(--(A1:A4=D1)*--(C1:C4=D2)),B1:B4)`