# Excel MATCH + COUNTIF function: retrieving the nth value in an array

Tags: excel, function, countif, excel-match

I have a formula that I'm using in Excel to return the row # of the first item that matches a specified value.

Formula: `=MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1,List),0)` + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and in Mac: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

Becomes:

```
MATCH(0,{**0**;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0},0)
```

Outputs: 1

I would like to update the function so that I can find the 2nd, 3rd, etc. instance that matches the specified value.

Like This:

```
MATCH(0,{0;**0**;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0},0)
```

And this outputs: 2

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588286/match-or-vlookup-starting-from-the-end-of-the-range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't your current formula find the position of the first value in list that **doesn't** match B1?

For 2nd try this array formula

`=SMALL(IF(List<>$B$1,ROW(List)-MIN(ROW(List))+1),2)`

replace the `2` with any value n for nth match. Assumes List is a single column

Comment: That fits like a glove with one small modification, an equals sign instead of the less than or greater than: =SMALL(IF(List=$B$1,ROW(List)-MIN(ROW(List))+1),2)

Comment: @user1311882 - no problem - like I said I was trying to make it consistent with your original, if you match zero against the COUNTIF you are finding the position of the first cell that  is `not equal` to $B$1 - to find the position of the first instance of $B$1 you would simply use `=MATCH($B$1,List,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the list dynamically every time an occurrence is found so that for the next occurrence the list will begin from the last position found.

use this `MATCH(<Match value>,INDIRECT(" <column of data> " & <Last position found> +1 & ":<Column of Data><Last Row Of Data>"),0)+<Last position found>`

please see this : [filter dynamic](http://www.ferdinet.blogspot.com/2013/07/filtre-dynamique-avec-formule-excel.html)