# VLOOKUP starting from the end of the range

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, gs-vlookup

In Google Sheets, I have a table that looks like this:

```
 A      B    
ID1  data 123
ID2  data 234
ID1  data 456
ID2  data 567
```

I want to get `data 567` for `ID2`. Using `Match(...,0)` or `VLOOKUP(...,FALSE)`, I get the first value for ID2 - but I want the last.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588572) uses `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A4=D1),B1:B4)`, but I saw that the `1/(A1:A4=D1)` notation only works in Excel, not Google sheets.

[This link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/441634-vlookup-pick-last-duplicate-entries.html) suggests using `MATCH(...,1)`, but that only works for sorted keys, which I don't have!

[This VBA solution](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/vlookup-to-go-down-until-the-last-cell-with-data-and-copy-unmatched-data.11481/) will probably not work in Google Sheets either...

I can add additional hidden columns (may an `IsLast` column?), it that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formua in google docs

`=arrayformula(index(B:B,max(if(A1:A4=D1,row(A1:A4)))))`

Comment: Works! Never heard of `arrayformula` before, will learn more about it.

Comment: I ended up putting the `max(...)` part in a separate column called `LastIndex`, and used it several times (for cases where it's not found, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in google sheets:
    =VLOOKUP(max(A:A),B:B,1)

Comment: D'oh! you're right - my sheet has numeric in columnA. @barry-houdini 's solution looks a lot better, actually:
<img src="http://imgur.com/KG9Zo2B">